# Не получается загрузить Preview в SubsamplingScaleImageView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте,
я использую библиотеку SubsamplingScaleImageView для загрузки изображений из файлов. При попытке добавить уменьшенное изображение preview, чтобы на время загрузки основного тяжелого изображения было сразу временно загружено его уменьшенная копия, у меня сразу падает приложение с ошибкой. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать? Я новичок пока, сильно не ругайте..

```
 String Img_Path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "1.jpg";

        Bitmap preview;
        BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Img_Path, option);
        float max = Math.max(((float) option.outWidth) / 1024.0f, ((float) option.outHeight) / 1024.0f);
        if (max > 1.0f) {
            option.inSampleSize = (int) max;
        }
        option.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        preview = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Img_Path, option);

        SubsamplingScaleImageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri(Img_Path), ImageSource.bitmap(preview));
```

Comment: `у меня сразу падает приложение с ошибкой` с какой?

Comment: `String Img_Path = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/1.jpg";` - слэш наверное забыли

Comment: Тут ошибка именно когда добавляешь вторым параметром ImageSource.bitmap(preview).. Видел что многие используют эту библиотеку, может кто сталкивался.. С одним параметром работает.. Слэш да, забыл пока тут печатал, у меня в приложении другой путь, но приложение падает от добавления второго параметра preview.. Я его и с пустым путем добавлял, и с файлом вместо Bitmap, всеравно вылетает программа и все..

Comment: Вот так работает    SubsamplingScaleImageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri(Img_Path)); А второй параметр специально задуман, чтобы выводить превью, пока грузится основное изображение..